# How to query for all Artifacts of a Milestone

Tags: rally

I am attempting to create reports on Milestones using App SDK 2.0 and would like to find all User Stories that have been assigned to the Milestone.

I tried pulling out the Artifacts from a Milestone using getCollection.

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model : 'Milestone',

    filters : [ {
        property : 'ObjectID',
        operator : '=',
        value : milestone.get("ObjectID")
    } ],
    fetch : [ 'Artifacts' ],
    limit : Infinity,
    autoLoad : true,
    listeners : {
        load : function(store, records) {
            var record = records[0];
            var info = record.get('Artifacts');
            var count = info.Count;
            record.getCollection('Artifacts').load({
                fetch : [ 'ObjectID' ],
                callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(artifact) {
                        console.log(artifact.get('ObjectID'));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel(): Could not find registered
>   factory for type:  Artifact  sdk-debug.js:7078

From https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/, it doesn't seem that Milestones is query able on the User Story or PortfolioItem. I tried it anyway using Tasks syntax and it nothing was returned.

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model : 'UserStory',
        filters : [ {
        property : 'Milestones',
        operator : 'contains',
        value : milestone.get("_ref")
    } ],
    fetch : [ 'ObjectID' ],
    limit : Infinity,
    autoLoad : true,
    listeners : {
        load : function(store, records) {
            console.log(records);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a defect in AppSDK2 that it does not work with abstract types, e.g. Artifact, UserPermissions.
Your first code example ran into that defect.
But your second code example must work. I suspect if it does not work for you it is a matter of scoping. Perhaps the milestone you filter by is not in the project you are scoped to. You may hard code a project ref in the context of the store to make sure it is looking in the right project. I initially tested your code in my default project and it worked as is, and then I modified it as follows to make sure it finds a milestone in a non-default project:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model : 'UserStory',
            context:{
                project: '/project/16662089077'
            },
            filters : [
                {
                    property : 'Milestones',
                    operator : 'contains',
                    value : "/milestone/33215216897" 
                }
            ],
            fetch : [ 'ObjectID' ],
            limit : Infinity,
            autoLoad : true,
            listeners : {
                load : function(store, records) {
                    console.log(records);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I have a question regarding the accepted parameters for the model field. From what I read in the guides, and from what I see in the Rally API 2.0, whatever is in the ObjectModel is what you can put there. But I see that if you use UserStory it works. Where can you see the allowed values for models?